# Como hacer que submit tenga dos funcionalidades - jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, formularios, dom

Tengo un input de tipo submit y otro input de tipo search (Es un formulario para buscar) en mi página. El cual necesito que al dar click en submit se despliegue el search(inicialmente está oculto), luego que al dar click otra vez en submit busque lo que se escribió en search.

Por el momento funciona casi como lo necesito pero el input search tiene required, me lo piden que funcione igual sin que tenga required.

Ya tengo la funcionalidad de buscar, pero no la de abrir el search al primer click y buscar al segundo click en submit.
También que al dar click en cualquier otra parte que no se sea submit, se cierre el input search.

La funcionalidad es como el de esta página:
[search-page](https://www.citiustech.com/default?location=worldwide)

```js
//Muestra el search.
$('.search-submit').click(function() {
        $('.search-input').fadeIn();
    });
```

```css
form {
display: flex;
position: relative;
padding: 10px;
background-color: beige;
width: 100%;
padding: 20px;
}

input[type=search] {
display: none;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
background: lightblue;
border: 1px solid gray;
padding: 5px 10px;
font-size: 14px;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
}

input[type=submit] {
background-color: orange;
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: auto;
border: 0;
padding: 5px;
position: absolute;
left: 200px;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="search" method="get" action="" role="search">
    <input class="search-input" type="search" name="s" required>
    <input class="search-submit" type="submit" role="button" value="search">
</form>
```

Comment: Lo que dices aquí: *«El cual necesito que al dar click en submit se despliegue el search, luego que al dar click otra vez en submit busque lo que se escribió en search...»*  es ilógico desde el punto de vista de la experiencia del usuario. Debería ser lo contrario, primero aparecería el el input donde se escribiría el término a buscar y cuando se escriban datos en él aparecería o se activaria el botón `Buscar`. No entiendo por qué tanta complicación ¿? Cuando haces un programa algo fundamental es que éste sea amigable y fácil de usar y nada mejor que el sentido común para hacerlo posible.

Comment: @xelfury No es necesario que descalifiques la opinión de alguien más para validar la tuya. Saludos.

Comment: @xelfury se llama fomentar las buenas prácticas, pero si te es difícil comprenderlo por mi esta bien. Saludos.

Comment: @xelfury Déjalo hasta ahí, veo que es tiempo perdido. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui te pongo un ejemplo de como puedes hacer lo que quieres con jquery. Ejecuta el codigo de abajo. Incluso te inclui la navegacion para que te des una idea de como incluirla con el search. Nota que el boton search en el primer click, despliega el input de busqueda y en el segundo click (si es que el usuario escribio algo), postea el form. Pero tambien nota que si el usuario no postea nada, el input no desaparece, el usuario tendria que volver a dar click en search para que desaparezca el input o dar click en otro lugar en el documento, solo para que lo tengas en cuenta al colocar tus menus si esque vas a usar esto en una barra de navegacion.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Document</title>
   <!-- Jquery -->
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
   <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#searchButton').click(function(event) {
            var $value = $('#searchValue').val();
            if ($value === "") {
               $('#searchValue').toggle("slide", {
                  direction: 'right'
               });
               event.preventDefault();
            } else {
               return true;
            }
         });
         $(document).on("click", function(event) {
            if (!$(event.target).closest(".searchForm").length) {
               $("#searchValue").hide();
               // Showing the hint message
            }
         });
      });
   </script>
   <style>
      .nav {
         display: flex;
         box-sizing: border-box;
         width: 100%;
         background-color: beige;
         align-items: center;
      }
      .nav a {
         text-decoration: none;
         padding: 10px;
         color: brown;
         text-transform: uppercase;
         font-family: sans-serif;
         font-weight: bold;
      }
      .nav a:hover {
         background-color: burlywood;
      }
      .searchForm {
         position: relative;
      }
      .searchValue {
         display: none;
         background: lightblue;
         border: 1px solid gray;
         padding: 5px 10px;
         font-size: 14px;
         width: 200px;
         position: absolute;
         left: -216px;
         z-index: 1;
      }
      .searchButton {
         background-color: orange;
         border: none;
         padding: 7px;
         margin: 0px 10px;
      }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="nav">
      <div style="flex-grow: 1;"></div>
      <a href="#">Menu</a>
      <a href="#">Menu</a>
      <a href="#">Menu</a>
      <form id="searchForm" method="GET" class="searchForm">
         <input type="text" name="search" id="searchValue" class="searchValue">
         <button type="submit" id="searchButton" name="search" value="submit" class="searchButton">Search</button>
      </form>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Agrega una variable para saber el estado del *input*, cuando hagas clic en el botón analizas esa variable para mostrar el *input* o procesar el formulario.

Para ocultarlo, agrega el evento *onclick* al documento, donde analizas si el clic no involucra botón o el mismo *input*.

```js
//Muestra el search.
let oculto = true;

$(document).click(function() {
    // Ocultar cuando el clic no fue en botón ni input
    if($(event.target).attr('class') != 'search-submit' && $(event.target).attr('class') != 'search-input') {
        $('.search-input').fadeOut();
        oculto = true;
    }
});

$('.search-submit').click(function() {
    if(oculto) {
        // Mostrar solo si está oculto
        $('.search-input').fadeIn();
        oculto = false;
        // Evitar que se procese el formulario
        event.preventDefault();
    } else {
        // Si vas a hacer una petición AJAX
        // También deberías evitar el proceso normal del formulario
        // De lo contrario, no es necesaria otra acción
    }
});
```

```css
form {
display: flex;
position: relative;
padding: 10px;
background-color: beige;
width: 100%;
padding: 20px;
}

input[type=search] {
display: none;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
background: lightblue;
border: 1px solid gray;
padding: 5px 10px;
font-size: 14px;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
}

input[type=submit] {
background-color: orange;
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: auto;
border: 0;
padding: 5px;
position: absolute;
left: 200px;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="search" method="get" action="" role="search">
    <input class="search-input" type="search" name="s" required>
    <input class="search-submit" type="submit" role="button" value="search">
</form>
```